# Print Odd and Even Number in List Using Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

Get the Value from user and Print the Odd and Even Number using List in Python

Comment: Do you prefer one-liner?

Answer (score 1):

would you like to try this code which simplify the flow and make it more `Pythonic`:

```
nums = map(int, input("Input some numbers: ").split())  # get all numbers in one shot 

results = [[], []]      # declare the results to store evens and odds

for n in nums:          # put each number in their own list or bucket. one shot.
    results[n % 2].append(n)
    

print(results)

evens, odds = results             # unpacking these 2 lists

print(f' evens list: {evens}' )   # confirm the results is ok
print(f' odds list: {odds} ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number = int(input("Enter How Many Number you want!"))
values=[]
for i in range(0,number):
    add = int(input("Enter Next Number:"))
    values.append(add)

print("Numbers in the list",values)

def oddEven(valuesList):
    OddResult = []
    EvenResult = []
    for i in valuesList:
        if i % 2== 0:
            EvenResult.append(i)
        else:
            OddResult.append(i)
    return OddResult,EvenResult

OddResult, EvenResult = oddEven(values)
print("Print Even Number ",EvenResult)
print("Print Odd Number",OddResult)
```

Comment: Try to avoid using built-in `list` as the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the code below to solve this, but please at least make an effort to answer the question before asking.

```
# Get the Value from user and Print the Odd and Even Number using List in Python

number = int(input("How many numbers do you want? "))
lst=[]
for i in range(0,number):
    add = int(input("Enter Number: "))
    lst.append(add)

even = []
odd = []

for num in lst:
    if num % 2==0:
        even += [num]
    else:
        odd += [num]
print("even: ", even)
print('odd: ', odd)
```

Comment: It seems that you are `input ` a series of numbers: ` 1 2 3 4 5 ...`? Correct?